# How do I join same table multiple times for multiple columns efficiently in less query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have to join a table multiple times in a mysql query, I don't want to do left join for each column. my tables and sql are-

**table_mst-**

```
id  name    result1 result2 result3
1    A       1       3       3
2    B       2       2       2
3    C       4       4       1
4    D       5       3       2
5    E       2       2       2
```

**store_pick-**

```
id  store_id    pick_id pick_name
1   result       1      pass
2   result       2      fail
3   result       3      supply
4   result       4      grace
5   result       5      ufm
```

**SQL-**

```
 SELECT
  tm.name,
  sp1.pick_name AS result1,
  sp2.pick_name AS result2,
  sp3.pick_name AS result3,
  sp4.pick_name AS result4
FROM table_mst AS tm
  LEFT JOIN store_pick AS sp1
    ON sp1.pick_id = tm.result1
      AND sp1.store_id = 'result'
  LEFT JOIN store_pick AS sp2
    ON sp2.pick_id = tm.result2
      AND sp2.store_id = 'result'
  LEFT JOIN store_pick AS sp3
    ON sp3.pick_id = tm.result3
      AND sp3.store_id = 'result'
  LEFT JOIN store_pick AS sp4
    ON sp4.pick_id = tm.result4
      AND sp4.store_id = 'result'
```

How to do it without using multiple left join for store_pick table?

Comment: Normalize your data.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What is wrong with your existing query? It is correct.

Comment: Hi. Do *what*? We can't read your mind. Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve]. Also this is a faq, google my comments re googling questions.

Answer (score 2):

No need for all these joins, you can use the `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT
  tm.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN sp1.pick_id = tm.result1 THEN sp1.pick_name END) AS Result1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN sp1.pick_id = tm.result2 THEN sp1.pick_name END) AS Result2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN sp1.pick_id = tm.result3 THEN sp1.pick_name END) AS Result3
FROM Table_mst as tm
LEFT JOIN store_pick AS sp1  ON sp1.store_id = 'result'
GROUP BY tm.name;
```

- [**sample demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1545/8)

And you will get the exact same results you got from the original query:

```
| name | Result1 | Result2 | Result3 |
|------|---------|---------|---------|
|    A |    pass |  supply |  supply |
|    B |    fail |    fail |    fail |
|    C |   grace |   grace |    pass |
|    D |     ufm |  supply |    fail |
|    E |    fail |    fail |    fail |
```

Comment: using `CASE` like this works well for small tables and this is a good solutions for this problem. I can add only you can put it in a view to reuse code

Comment: To readers: this answer is known as the conditional aggregate, an often used method for pivoting (long to wide) query data.